# Are users automatically notified when an answer to their question is edited?

Tags: support, inbox

The title says it all.

I'm trying to think back to recall whether I have ever been notified when an answer to one of my questions was edited, but I can't recall.

Comment: Neither do I. Maybe there's a bounty on the question? Or it could be a new feature

Comment: @Manishearth It hasn't happened to me; I was merely wondering if it would.  I actually feel that might be rather excessive if that were a feature of SE.

Comment: Whoops - read the question completely wrong - ignore that answer. I've never seen such a notification.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Ok cool.

Comment: Oh, I see I misread the question. I thought you were talking about edits on your own answer. Ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

No, no notifications are generated if an answer to one of your questions is edited.

However, if you go to your profile and sort your questions by Activity, recent edits to answers will cause questions to rank more highly in that list (as will new answers, edits to the question itself, etc.)